# Lambda Function using c# cannot invoke external HTTPS APIs

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am trying to invoke External APIs from AWS lambda function written in c#.  The Lamda function is deployed in `No VPC` mode. I am calling this function from Alexa skill. The code works fine for an `http` request, but its not working for `https`.

The below code works when I use `http://www.google.com`.

But, if I replace http with https, then I get the error in the cloud watch saying:

> "Process exited before completing request."

Even the log written in catch is not getting logged in cloud watch.

```cs
public class Function
{
    public const string INVOCATION_NAME = "bingo";

    public async Task<SkillResponse> FunctionHandler(SkillRequest input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var requestType = input.GetRequestType();
        if (requestType == typeof(IntentRequest))
        {
            string response = "";
            IntentRequest request = input.Request as IntentRequest;
            response += $"About {request.Intent.Slots["carmodel"].Value}";
            
            try
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Trying to access internet"); 
                    //var resp=httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com").Result // this works perfect!                   
                    var resp = httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.google.com").Result; // this throws error
                    Console.WriteLine("Call was successful");
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception from main function " + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);

            }            
            return MakeSkillResponse(response, true);
        }
        else
        {
            return MakeSkillResponse(
                    $"I don't know how to handle this intent. Please say something like Alexa, ask {INVOCATION_NAME} about Tesla.",
                    true);
        }
    }

    private SkillResponse MakeSkillResponse(string outputSpeech, bool shouldEndSession,
        string repromptText = "Just say, tell me about car models to learn more. To exit, say, exit.")
    {
        var response = new ResponseBody
        {
            ShouldEndSession = shouldEndSession,
            OutputSpeech = new PlainTextOutputSpeech { Text = outputSpeech }
        };

        if (repromptText != null)
        {
            response.Reprompt = new Reprompt() { OutputSpeech = new PlainTextOutputSpeech() { Text = repromptText } };
        }

        var skillResponse = new SkillResponse
        {
            Response = response,
            Version = "1.0"
        };
        return skillResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing response = await httpClient.GetAsync(..).Result; your code there doesn't wait for the http request to complete .

Comment: Thanks for the response!. I thought .Result would wait for the response. Any ways, I changed it to await but no luck. Strage part is code works perfect for http request but not working for https.

Comment: It probably means you're getting an exception, enclose your code in a try/catch block and console.log the exception? Any for the record your a very naughty boy, always handle exceptions ;-)

Comment: "Process exited before completing request." message is from try/catch logged in cloud watch. My question is should we have to take care of any extra things for https calls?

Comment: You're logging out the full exception? That's odd let me do some reading quickly.

Comment: So you might have to, but until we get the proper exception from the try catch it's hard to tell.

Comment: When the above error occurs, system is not even logging the log statements written inside "catch". I doubt if control is getting inside "catch". It seems like platform is directly exiting the Function by throwing the above mentioned error.

Comment: Yeah the thing is, that Lambda will only exit if a) you tell it to, b) an exception c) a timeout - could you post the complete function or add me to a GitHub repo where your function code is so I can look?

Comment: I have updated the full Function code above in the question. Its a simple GetAsync call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by updating the library version.

`System.Net.Http v4.3.4` was not completely compatible with dotnet core `v1`.

So outbound http calls were working but not https calls. Changing the version of System.net.http resolved the issue.

Comment: Can you please update with the correct/working code?